# Error ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XX.app' does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: air, application-loader

I'm using Application loader 2.9.1 to submit application built by adobe flash player CS 6 with AIR SDK 15

First i submit .ipa but got error: Unable to extract archive.
So i searching and find way:
-extract .ipa
-inside payload > .zip the xx.app folder

Then i send .zip file and got Error:
Error ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XX.app' does not contain a bundle executable

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've solved this issue. The error caused by a folder inside .app that folder name is same as application's name. I change the folder name, re-compiled, and uploaded successfully

Hope this info usefull for anyone experiencing same problem.

Cheers

Comment: I have no such folder having same name as application's name. But still I'm not able to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just change .ipa extension to .zip directly, then try to send again.

Comment: i have try to upload .zip but got this message:
Unable to Upload package
The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive. Please make sure /.../.../XX.zip is a valid zip or ipa archive