# Xcode App Submisson ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission, itunes-store

When I am submitting Application through Xcode Application validation successful but when submit to Appstore Then This error Occur.

> ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'example.app' does not contain a bundle executable

I also try Application loader Version 3.1 but same error occur.
I refer all link like 

[link 1](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/198206/application-loader-error-90207.html?sort=oldest) 
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793854/error-itms-90207-invalid-bundle) 
[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057046/error-itms-9000-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-xx-app-does-not-contain-a-bund) 
[link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424431/invalid-bundle-structure-ios)

[image]

Comment: Are you certain the file in the app bundle is executable etc?  Check with `file`.

Comment: @trojanfoe i check all  the files in bundle but i could not file executable files. please give some file extension which create this type of problems.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Please see my update comment above

Comment: So it looks like Apple is correct.  You are not creating a valid app bundle.  You should look into that, as there is almost certainly error messages you are missing.

Comment: @ilesh Have you any success in this? I'm banging my head on the desk because of the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Bundle. The bundle at '.app' does not contain a bundle executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369619/invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-app-does-not-contain-a-bundle-executable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The connection to the info.plist file might be causing the issue. Try changing the bundle id from target and check if it reflects in the plist file and vice-versa. If this doesn't reflects copy your plist file at some other location, remove it from the app and drag and drop again, it will help. This solved my issue, hope it helps.

Comment: Changes are reflecting in plist file. But still getting the error. Not able to upload.

Answer (score 11):

Please check your info.plist file and add below key if not

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but solution above is not working.

Comment: will you plz provide me screen shot of your error.? @Manish Verma

Comment: @RahulPatel I solved it. Actually there exists the CFBundleExecutable key in the plist file but my plist contained some characters which made it invalid xml. So after removing invalid characters my app uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this error since yesterday and when I was about to give up I tried with a different Mac and it worked, the only difference between the OSX was that I updated to Xcode 8.2.1 and the other OSX had 8.2.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was banging my head on the desk for several days.  I tried all solutions posted online and nothing worked.  For me it ended up being corruption in my 'Bundle display name' (aka CFBundleDisplayName) key in my info plist file.  There was a rogue '¿' character that would not get removed when I changed the entry in Xcode (I know this because I tried setting several keys within Xcode).  I had to remove the key and re-add it get it fixed.  The only way I ever saw this was to open the plist with a text editor.  Xcode never rendered the bad character.  If you are seeing this issue check you plist file in a text editor for any bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error during upload, I was pretty sure about the bundle structure is perfect, the executable at the correct place and the Info.plist points to the correct place, contains the correct name, just like the localized versions.
I decided to ask for help from the Apple support. After a long process it is turned out that my `~/.itmstransporter` folder was corrupt or outdated.
After deleted the folder it is re-created automatically and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was because i moved application loader to another disk. After moving it back to mac os disk, it works fine.